# AmCharts - zooming to selection snaps to nearest points instead of selected date range

Tags: javascript, charts, amcharts

In the example CodePen, http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vKabjQ,  I would like to select a blank area on the chart and not have it snap to the nearest points.

For example, given there is a dummy point 7 days from now, if I select either side of the 'now' line, it zooms to the dummy point instead of showing the 'now' line guide as I would expect.

Selection:
[image]

Actual Result:
[image: Result]

Expected:
[image]

Another example: If I select points on the graph with some blank space included, AmCharts will ignore the date range I selected and truncate the selected range to the last point.

[image]

Result:
[image]

Note: If I instead use the zoom scrollbar to select the date ranges, it will happily select a blank area without snapping.  I would like the selection logic to behave the same way.

CodePen code - http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vKabjQ:

```
var now = new Date();
var chartData = generateChartData(now);
var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
    "type": "serial",
    "theme": "light",
    "dataProvider": chartData,
    "valueAxes": [{
      "includeAllValues": true
    }],
  "guides": [
    {
      "date": now,
      "lineColor": "#CCCCCC",
      "lineAlpha": 1,
      "lineThickness": 2,
      "dashLength": 10,
      "inside": true,
      "labelRotation": 90,
      "label": "now"
  }],
    "mouseWheelZoomEnabled": true,
    "graphs": [{
        "id": "g1",
        "valueField": "value",
    }],
    "chartScrollbar": {
        "graph": "g1",
        "scrollbarHeight": 50
    },
    "chartCursor": {
      "cursorPosition": "mouse"
    },
    "categoryField": "date",
    "categoryAxis": {
        "parseDates": true,
    }
});

function generateChartData(now) {
    var chartData = [];
    var firstDate = new Date();
    firstDate.setDate(firstDate.getDate() - 150);

    for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        var newDate = new Date(firstDate);
        newDate.setDate(newDate.getDate() + i);

        var value = Math.random();

        chartData.push({
            date: newDate,
            value: value
        });
    }

    var weekAhead = new Date(now);
    weekAhead.setDate(weekAhead.getDate() + 7)

    chartData.push({
      date: weekAhead,
      dummy: true
    });

    return chartData;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is actually a problem I faced multiple times now, as it seems that there's no property for the [`chartCursor`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/ChartCursor) to change this behaviour of getting the closest data points as selection range.

My workaround for this is configuring the [`chartCursor`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/ChartCursor) to stop zooming automatically and instead, hook up a custom handler on the [`zoomed`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/ChartCursor#zoomed) event. Then you can access the actual selected time range from the cursor and manually zoom the chart.
It is necessary to get the two dates into the right order, so the `zoom` function will work properly.

```
chart.chartCursor.addListener("selected", function(o) {
    var start = Math.min(o.target.timestamp0, o.target.timestamp);
    var end = Math.max(o.target.timestamp0, o.target.timestamp);
    chart.zoom(start, end);
});
```

See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/x6L0rcpc/) for a working demo.

Comment: Just to complement @gerric solution, which should work, there's another option: instead of having on empty data point in the future, fill an empty data point for each day that leads up to it. It should make chart cursor zoom nicely.

Comment: @gerric, works great!  I had actually attempted something similar but was using event.start and event.end - using event.target.timestamp and event.target.timestamp0 was the answer.

Comment: @martynasma - for simple charts yes...this is actually what I have been doing as a workaround however the implementation was starting to get messy given we need support for varying sample periods, gaps in data, multiple series and dynamic loading.  Nonetheless, thanks for an alternative!